# How to remove a class when opening another accordion

Tags: jquery

I have an accordion. When you click on **a**, the "active" class is added to it, it opens, and the adjacent one closes. But the neighboring class remains "active" if it was opened before. The class is removed only when the element is clicked again. And if you click on another, then it still has the "active" class. How can I remove the class from the rest of the elements when clicking on one of the items? And also toggleClass when second click.

```js
const menuLink = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-link");
const subMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
$(menuLink).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(subMenu).slideUp();
  $(this).next().is(":visible") || $(this).next().slideDown();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a class="menu-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Sub menu link 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <a class="menu-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Sub menu link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <a class="menu-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Sub menu link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML (in a [mre] of the issue you are having) for faster troubleshooting

Comment: Added HTML for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `.not()` :

```
$('.menu-link').not(this).removeClass("active");
```

This will remove active class to all except the one you are currently clicking

```js
const menuLink = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-link");
const subMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
$(menuLink).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('.menu-link').not(this).removeClass("active");

  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(subMenu).slideUp();
  $(this).next().is(":visible") || $(this).next().slideDown();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a class="menu-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Sub menu link 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <a class="menu-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Sub menu link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <a class="menu-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Sub menu link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```